# Test sharepoint online/on-premises using sharepoint mobile app simulators

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, mobile

We have many sharepoint online and on-premises site collections and i want to test them using sharepoint mobile app, mainly for these platforms:-

1. iPhone
2. Android
3. Windows

now my PC is windows 7 and i have a VM which have windows 10. so can i install simulators for the sharepoint app inside my windows 7 & 10? as otherwise it will be challenging to have 3 phones (iPhone,Android & windows) + for on-premises sites, we will need to configure VPN access on these phones. since everything is already configured inside my PC (windows 7/10) so not sure if i can use simulators for sharepoint mobile app inside my windows PC? i need to test how accessing sharepoint lists/libraries will looks like, and our customization on these lists and libraries. I do not need to test accessing sharepoint using mobile browsers, i am talking about testing sharepoint using mobile apps.
Thanks